# PHP PDO Error & Success messages

Tags: php, pdo

I just recently converted my SQLi to PDO.  I am not 100% certain how to prepare a PDO statement to include an `ERROR` or `SUCCESS` statement.  I have included part of my code below:

```
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO data (avatar,citid,birthday,citname,level,experience,rank,rankimage,elite_citizen,points,strength,status,citizenship,mu,date) VALUES (:avatar,:citid,:birthday,:citname,:level,:experience,:rank,:rankimage,:elite_citizen,:points,:strength,:status,:citizenship,:mu,:date)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':avatar'=>$avatar,':citid'=>$citid,':birthday'=>$birthday,':citname'=>$citname,':level'=>$level,':experience'=>$experience,':rank'=>$rank,':rankimage'=>$rankimage,':elite_citizen'=>$elite_citizen,':points'=>$points,':strength'=>$strength,':status'=>$status,':citizenship'=>$citizenship,':mu'=>$mu,':date'=>$date));
```

In MYSQL, I found it easier to use the statement below:

```
// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

How would i accomplish the same for PDO?

Comment: Two questions. 1. What exactly you want to do in case of error? 2. Why do you think there would be an error at all?

Comment: i have a scheduled task that runs and records `error` or `success` on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, i customize the either message so that i can check where its going wrong, the main problem i have is that each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` can take 1 minute as it pulls data for `JSON` remotely

Comment: Imagine there is an error in the statement above. What certainly doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: i need the error statement for a reason, the JSON API can often fail as it has a limit, i depend on it working 90% of the time if i don't have an error statement then i will be unsure it worked, i am not using the above for a data entry form, its a file that automatically runs that will auto insert the data without having to use a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I accomplish the same for PDO?

PDO uses exceptions ( by default ). Which means you can use a `try-catch` block to catch the exception if it occurs and print an error message.

In case everything goes well, the error message block will be skipped, in case an error occurs the success message will be skipped and the catch block will be run.

```
try {
    // pdo code
    // success message
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    // error message
}
```

In your specific case:

```
try {
    $sql = "...";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(...));
    echo 'Good'; // success message
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Bad'; // error message
}
```

Comment: thank you for the above example it worked, i will use your example

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question answered if your problem is resolved.  And don't be afraid to [read the documentation on PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i am very new to PDO, so i will have plenty yo learn, i will read the above url, i always thought PDO would be difficult

Comment: @YourCommonSense i have tried the above and it works for me, i am currently using `PHPJobScheduler` to do scheduled tasks to run the file every 4 hours, the problem i first had with `PDO` was no error or success statement i tried the above and it worked for me unless there is a better method, i am very new to PDO so i am open to suggestions

Answer (score -1):

By checking the return result of `execute`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `data` (`avatar`) VALUES (:avatar)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$res = $stmt->execute(array(':avatar' => $avatar));

if ($res === true) {
    echo 'Success';
}
else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```